# How can I reset a world in Minecraft from a button within the game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am creating a playable chess game in minecraft. Everything works fine but I don't know how to reset my map from within the game.

I already know that I can just backup my world save file and then reload whenever I want. But, I don't think that method is much convenient.

I wanted a simple, clean and easy way of resetting the map from within the game. Like you press a button and it reloads.

Comment: You can not *reset* a map, because Minecraft does not save previous state. Write some commands to delete pieces and construct pieces where they should be.

Answer (score 3):

As others stated before, this cannot be done in Vanilla Survival MC and needs either mods or command blocks.

Basically create the chessboard somewhere in your world (preferably in the spawn chunks) in it start up state. This is your template board.
Before starting a new chess game, clone the template board to the location of your liking.
Use the same technique to clear the board (create empty template board and clone that).

Example use of clone command: `/clone 100 50 100 108 52 108 ~ ~ ~ /replace`

The 6 numbers are two coordinates, each pointing to the cube you want to clone, the three tildes (~) are a coordinate relative to where you stand (so currently the block on the first coordinate of the cube will be cloned to where you stand).

Finding the appropriate coordinates is a bit tricky, so I recommend reading the Wiki entry for it (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands). There are also plenty of tutorials to be found (for example: https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/clone_command.php)

Comment: Commandblocks are vital part of vanilla MC, so your first sentence is kinda misleading. However the words "you need to enable cheats to prepare it" would be more correct.

Comment: @Antoine: I've added that it cannot be done in survival mc, what was meant but not made clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you use command blocks for the game then you can add some more to reset the board into a initial state when a button gets pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Structure blocks. Set a command block to set redstone block next to it in load mode bam redstones gone map reloaded. Easy and I just made a Skyblock with this reset button but it's only for a area you designed

Answer (score -2):

Clone the build. reclone when u want 2 restart.

/clone (co-ordinates of 1 corner of build) (co-ordinates of opposite corner of build) (Where u want build 2 be cloned)